# MapServer displays raster on top other layers

Tags: raster, mapserver, ms4w

I have a problem. MapServer displays raster on top other layers. Is there any way to put raster beneath the map?

```
MAP
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT         466914.4981 5983965.6134 469588.2900 5986580.8550
   SIZE           300 300
  SHAPEPATH      "../data"
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255
 
    
     # Start of LAYER DEFINITIONS ---------------------------------------------
  LAYER # States polygon layer begins here
    NAME         "Pelke_rastras"
    DATA         "raster\Pelke_rastras4.tif"
    STATUS       ON
    TYPE         RASTER
    

   CLASS
      NAME       "Krakinis 1995"

         
      END
    END
  END # States polygon layer ends here
  
  # End of LAYER DEFINITIONS -------------------------------
  
  # Start of LAYER DEFINITIONS ---------------------------------------------
  LAYER # States polygon layer begins here
    NAME         Pelkinis_miskas
    DATA         Pelkinis_miskas1
    STATUS       OFF
    TYPE         POLYGON

   CLASS
      NAME       "Krakinis 1995"

      
      STYLE
        COLOR        102 204 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 76 153 0
      END
    END
  END 





<h3 align="center"> Ežeras "Krakinis" 1995 m.</h3>
          <div align="center">
            <img border="1" src="http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/3LAB.map&layer=Pelke_rastras&layer=Pelkinis_miskas&layer=Pelke&layer=Ezeras&mode=map"
```

Comment: Do you use some WMS client for accessing your MapServer?

Comment: request the layers in the other order

Comment: Have you checked the polygon layer alone? Does it work? I am not sure what happens with many `&layer=`.  By the documentation you shoud use `&layers=` with a list https://mapserver.org/cgi/controls.html.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in CGI mode, you can use the `&layers=all` setting in the CGI request (and make sure that in your mapfile that each layer status is set to ON.  Here is an example (and working) CGI request:

- https://ms4w.dev/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/local-demo/local.map&MODE=browse&TEMPLATE=openlayers&LAYERS=all

Since your mapfile has your raster layer listed near the top, MapServer will draw it first (as it parses your mapfile from top-to-bottom), and then MapServer will place your polygon layer on top of the raster, in the output map image.